# How can I determine which dependency is determining other library's version?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have the following dependencies in an Android project:

```groovy
dependencies {
        implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02"
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
        implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
        implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.1'
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
        api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"
        implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads'
}
```

I would expect `core-ktx:1.3.2` to bring in `androidx.core:core:1.3.2`, but in the project pane, I can see that the actual dependency that has been brought in is `androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha02`. This is evidenced by the fact that I have access to newer APIs like `WindowInsetsCompat.getInsets()`, which didn't yet exist in 1.3.2.

I want to figure out why this different version of the library has been brought in. I assume one of my other dependencies is using 1.5.0-alpha02, but how can I tell which one without reading every POM file (and dependent POM files up the dependency chain)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend trying [the Gradle `dependencyInsight` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:identifying_reason_dependency_selection).

> Every Gradle project provides the task `dependencyInsight` to render the so-called *dependency insight report* from the command line. Given a dependency in the dependency graph you can identify the selection reason and track down the origin of the dependency selection.

---

I created a new project and pasted your dependencies in. Then I ran:

```
./gradlew app:dependencyInsight --configuration debugRuntimeClasspath --dependency "androidx.core:core"
```

This output a report that began with:

```
androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha02
\--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02
     +--- debugRuntimeClasspath
```

So it seems that `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02` depends on `androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha02`.

The report also says:

```
androidx.core:core:1.3.2 -> 1.5.0-alpha02
\--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2
     +--- debugRuntimeClasspath
```

So you are correct that `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2` brings in version `1.3.2`... it just happens to be overridden by appcompat's dependency.